# Can't find Component inspector tool in Codenameone Simulator

Tags: codenameone

i use Windows 10 and NetBeans 12.4, no update for Codenameone plugin available.

Codenameone should have a component inspector tool in its simulator (at simulate -> component inspector), but i can't find it there.

Can someone help?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was moved from the simulator menu to the tools menu next to it. Took me a second to find it too.